# How to select last child of one of the div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to get the last `selected` elements. It can be in any of the `main` and in any position inside the div.
Also, the number of `main` & `sub` div can vary.

I tried using `:last-child` but it does not work in the uncle elements.

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub selected" />
  <div class="sub selected" />
  <div class="sub selected" />
<div/>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub selected" />
  <div class="sub selected" />
  <div class="sub" />
<div/>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub" />
  <div class="sub" />
  <div class="sub" />
<div/>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] and correct the invalid HTML and add the CSS you tried

Comment: JS would be a solution

Answer (score 0):

That would include going up and down the DOM tree to check the next "cousins".
CSS does'nt do that.
I suppose there won't be any :last-of-class anytime near in the future.